# EXCEL - count cells in column that fall within a specific month iin another column

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, countif, sumifs

Firstly, this website was amazing at answering a previous excel question I had.  In an excel spread sheet, I have several columns - COLUMN D (Date property empty), COLUMN G (Date property filled), COLUMN H (Number of days property was empty).  What I now need to do is add up all the rows in column H, but, only count the properties which were filled in a particular month.  So, if a property was re-let in March, I want it to add up the number of days it was empty (Column H) along with all of the other properties that were filled in march.  I would have a separate line for each month of the year.  I don't want it to tell me the number of properties that were re-let in a particular month, I need it to calculate the days the property was empty when it was filled in a particular month.  I hope I'm making sense!

Comment: I'm glad to hear you've received good help in the past. Please go back and accept the answer which helped you the most in your previous question. You can do that by clicking the grey check mark to the left of the answer you wish to accept :)

Comment: All done...apologies :-)

Comment: no problem, but it doesn’t look like you’ve accepted an answer on your other question yet

Comment: Just tried again.